# Add a new plain action to a generated controller: object not found

Tags: symfony

I have just generated a bundle (`DefaultBundle`), an entity (`Manufacturer`) and its CRUD controller using `php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud --entity=DefaultBundle:Manufacturer`.

**The problem:**

when I try to add a new action to the generated controller like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/search", name="manufacturer_search")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function searchAction() 
{
    return new Response("foobar");
}
```

and request it like `app_dev.php/manufacturer/search`, I get this error:

> DefaultBundle\Entity\Manufacturer object not found. 404 Not Found -
>   NotFoundHttpException

This is the hole controller:

```
?php

namespace DefaultBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use DefaultBundle\Entity\Manufacturer;
use DefaultBundle\Form\ManufacturerType;

/**
 * Manufacturer controller.
 *
 * @Route("/manufacturer")
 */
class ManufacturerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Manufacturer entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="manufacturer_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $manufacturers = $em->getRepository('DefaultBundle:Manufacturer')->findAll();

        return $this->render('manufacturer/index.html.twig', array(
            'manufacturers' => $manufacturers,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Manufacturer entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="manufacturer_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $manufacturer = new Manufacturer();
        $form = $this->createForm('DefaultBundle\Form\ManufacturerType', $manufacturer);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($manufacturer);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('manufacturer_show', array('id' => $manufacturer->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('manufacturer/new.html.twig', array(
            'manufacturer' => $manufacturer,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Manufacturer entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="manufacturer_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(Manufacturer $manufacturer)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($manufacturer);

        return $this->render('manufacturer/show.html.twig', array(
            'manufacturer' => $manufacturer,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Manufacturer entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="manufacturer_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Manufacturer $manufacturer)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($manufacturer);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('DefaultBundle\Form\ManufacturerType', $manufacturer);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($manufacturer);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('manufacturer_edit', array('id' => $manufacturer->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('manufacturer/edit.html.twig', array(
            'manufacturer' => $manufacturer,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a Manufacturer entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="manufacturer_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Manufacturer $manufacturer)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($manufacturer);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($manufacturer);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('manufacturer_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Manufacturer entity.
     *
     * @param Manufacturer $manufacturer The Manufacturer entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Manufacturer $manufacturer)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('manufacturer_delete', array('id' => $manufacturer->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/search", name="manufacturer_search")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function searchAction() 
    {
        return new Response("foobar");
    }
}
```

And this is the path and the `Manufacturer` entity.
[image]
[image]

```
Stack Trace

    in var/cache/dev/classes.php at line 7597  -
        }
        }
        if (null === $object && false === $configuration->isOptional()) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('%s object not found.', $class));
        }
        $request->attributes->set($name, $object);
        return true;
    at DoctrineParamConverter ->apply (object(Request), object(ParamConverter))
    in var/cache/dev/classes.php at line 7777  +
    at ParamConverterManager ->applyConverter (object(Request), object(ParamConverter))
    in var/cache/dev/classes.php at line 7750  +
    at ParamConverterManager ->apply (object(Request), array('manufacturer' => object(ParamConverter)))
    in var/cache/dev/classes.php at line 7484  +
    at ParamConverterListener ->onKernelController (object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
    at call_user_func (array(object(ParamConverterListener), 'onKernelController'), object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php at line 61  +
    at WrappedListener ->__invoke (object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
    at call_user_func (object(WrappedListener), object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
    in var/cache/dev/classes.php at line 2167  +
    at EventDispatcher ->doDispatch (array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
    in var/cache/dev/classes.php at line 2082  +
    at EventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php at line 136  +
    at TraceableEventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 141  +
    at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 68  +
    at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
    in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php at line 169  +
    at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
    in web/app_dev.php at line 28  +

Logs  -
1 error

    INFO - Matched route "{route}".
    INFO - Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id_1 FROM manufacturer t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
    ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "DefaultBundle\Entity\Manufacturer object not found." at /var/www/prueba/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 7597
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".

Stack Trace (Plain Text)  -

[1] Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: DefaultBundle\Entity\Manufacturer object not found.
    at n/a
        in /var/www/prueba/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 7597

    at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter->apply(object(Request), object(ParamConverter))
        in /var/www/prueba/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 7777

    at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterManager->applyConverter(object(Request), object(ParamConverter))
        in /var/www/prueba/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 7750

    at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterManager->apply(object(Request), array('manufacturer' => object(ParamConverter)))
        in /var/www/prueba/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 7484

    at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener->onKernelController(object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
        in  line 

    at call_user_func(array(object(ParamConverterListener), 'onKernelController'), object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
        in /var/www/prueba/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php line 61

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
        in  line 

    at call_user_func(object(WrappedListener), object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
        in /var/www/prueba/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 2167

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
        in /var/www/prueba/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 2082

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
        in /var/www/prueba/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 136

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
        in /var/www/prueba/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 141

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /var/www/prueba/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 68

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /var/www/prueba/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php line 169

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /var/www/prueba/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the request URL be:

```
app_dev.php/search
```

Seems like that from your code. I'm not certain this is correct though, but can you try?

Comment: no, since there is this line in the controller: * `@Route("/manufacturer")`

Comment: Hmm, now I look at your error message, it's weird. It shows that the Entity Manufacturer is not found, yet you include this use statement: `use DefaultBundle\Entity\Manufacturer;` Does the Entity exist at that path?

Comment: @AlvinBunkd yes

Comment: You have double-checked correct? I'm not trying to be annoying, but that's what the message points to. There should be a path: src/DefaultBundle/Entity and then a file "Manufacturer.php" and inside that the statement "class Manufacturer". Make sure the case of the letters. Just trying to help you the best that I can...

Answer (score 0):

In the symfony's debug toolbar I have noticed that the route being requested is `manufacturer_show`. So I have just removed the corresponding action since I'm not using it and now when I request the URL I mention in my question (`manufacturer/search`), I reach the action I have just created (`searchAction`).

Answer (score 0):

Your search action needs to come before your show action. Symfony compiles the routes in order. Because your show pattern `"/{id}"` basically matches anything after a slash `"/search"` for instance your search method will not be reachable.

However if you move your search method above your show method and clear your cache the routes will work as intended.

Keep in mind this will also mean that you can have any "id"'s with a value of "search" or they wont be matched